# Creating a connection in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle databases(I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition) and sqldeveloper. I have this doubt

When creating a new connection in sqldeveloper what is actually happening?
Creating a new database or connecting to an existing databasE?

If I create multiple connections are they pointing to a single database or different databases, if the later then how to choose a database name while creating a connection

Answer (score 1):

You are establishing a connection to **user** (i.e. *schema*) which resides in an (Oracle) **database**. One database contains many users, so - create one connection per user.

Creating a connection does **NOT** create a new database; it is done differently. I don't think that 11gXE offers that option; you'd need a Standard or Enterprise Edition.

No problem if you use multiple databases (most of us do). I prefer keeping them in TNSNAMES.ORA file, in a directory used by the TNS_ADMIN environment variable. Currently, there are 94 databases I have access to, each of them having *many* users.

In your case, 11gXE is (probably) installed on your own computer, and you'll use one of its users (HR?), so - just *connect* to it. If it is locked, you'll have to unlock it first, though - in that case, create connection to SYS (don't forget to connect AS SYSDBA), then

```
ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr;
```

and then create connection to "hr" whose password is now set to "hr" (all lower case).